# Do I need to use Html.TextBox to use DataAnnotations validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm looking at this example:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

The example uses this syntax:

```
<label for="Name">Name:</label>
<%= Html.TextBox("Name") %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "*") %>
```

Is this needed to have a server side validation using those Attributes?

Comment: This is for Client-side validation. So: No, not absolutely necessary.

Comment: But to have the validation ClientSide I need it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The server-side validation is done by the [Modelbinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder(v=vs.118).aspx), so annotations will work assuming the modelbinder can find the fields (they need to have names that correspond to the input field).

Comment: The name of the fields should be case sensitive equal to the name of the properties?

Comment: Yes. Not sure about the case-sensitive part, but I think it might not matter.

Comment: However how can I tell the browser to show an error message and the controller to stop the validation?

Comment: Html.ValidationSummary() or Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property).

Comment: In the controller you can retrieve all the Errors from             ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors) and clear the validation by doing ModelState.Clear()

Comment: @Revious, Its not case sensitive, but otherwise it must match. Its better to use the strongly typed helpers so the framework does the correct naming for you - `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)` and `Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also provide validation in model  class itself for your property if you are using models. It requires DataAnnotation as a reference

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is Required")]
public string Textbox_NAME { get; set; }
```